# Web Service - Getting data in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

I'm new to this web service in iOS. I made a sample web service app and made the first stage  login successfully.  While checking the url in web after login I got this output :

```
<Rows>
<Row>
<style>LW6001TA</style>
<thumbnail1>
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
</thumbnail1>
</Row>
</Rows>
```

How to get these stuff back in Xcode and view it ? This is the first time I work on this web service I have no idea to get back this response back in Xcode. Please Help !

Comment: Xcode is the IDE you use to write apps. You are not getting it back in Xcode. You are looking to parse it with Objective-c or swift. Your question is far too broad for this site. There are many many tutorials online for how to fetch XML from a webservice and parse it. Please do some research online before asking others to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)parseTheData
{
    //Here convert your response to NSData type (NSData *data = [NSData data]; , i have used just for example)
    NSData *data = [NSData data];
    // Make sure that there is data.
    if (data != nil) {
        self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        self.xmlParser.delegate = self;

        // Initialize the mutable string that we'll use during parsing.
        self.foundValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        // Start parsing.
        [self.xmlParser parse];
    }
}

//Delegate methods
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    // Initialize the array.
    self.arrNeighboursData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    // When the parsing has been finished then simply reload the table view or do what ever you want

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
    NSLog(@"%@", [parseError localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    // If the current element name is equal to "geoname" then initialize the temporary dictionary.
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"]) {
        self.dictTempDataStorage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    // Keep the current element.
    self.currentElement = elementName;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"thumbnail1"]) {
        // Store the data like this
        [self.dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:self.foundValue] forKey:@"thumbnail1"];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"style"]){
        // Store the data like this
        [self.dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:self.foundValue] forKey:@"style"];
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
    {
        //Add the dictionary in array and remove the data from dictionary, so that we can reuse the dictionary
        [self.arrNeighboursData addObject:self.dictTempDataStorage];
        self.dictTempDataStorage = nil;
    }

    // Clear the mutable string.
    [self.foundValue setString:@""];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    // Store the found characters if only we're interested in the current element.
    if (![string isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [self.foundValue appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Here I am just showing you the way to move on.